# caffe filter out input with specific labels

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I am using Caffe to build a CNN, and I have encountered the following question.

Say that I have 3 parallel convolutional layer in my Network, and with an input image, I want to assign the image to specific convolutional layer with respect to its label. For example, input image with a "cat" label goes to convolutional layer1-1 and layer1-3, input image with a "dog" label goes to convolutional layer1-2 and layer1-3.

Is there any way to do so using Caffe? I have found out that there are one type of layer named "filter", but there are few documentation talking about its usage nor other examples online. Is this "filter" layer what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK there is not "conditional" forwarding in caffe. How would you compute derivatives of such architecture?